# Getting Custom Button Resource ID At Runtime

Tags: android, button, resources

I have a custom button called "mybutton.xml" located in my res/drawable folder. At runtime, I am creating a button at runtime, like so:

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);

myButton.setBackgroundResource(?); // <--- This line is where I need help
```

What I am trying to do is dynamically resolve my button name, "mybutton.xml" to a resource that I can pass to setBackgroundResource so that the button will use my custom button. How do I do this in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In case anyone else needs to do this, here is the code:

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);

myButton.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getIdentifier("myButton", "drawable",this.getPackageName()));
```

Hope this helps someone else out!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.id.mybutton) where the R.id.mybutton id matches the button id in your XML.

Comment: There is no button in my XML. I want to dynamically create the button at runtime.